# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(\frac{1+i}{2})^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(\frac{1+i}{2})^n$.

I don't know how to solve this limit. Should I use the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(\sqrt{2}/2)^n\cos(n \pi / 4)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(\sqrt{2}/2)^n\sin(n \pi / 4)$ for the real et imaginary part of $n(\frac{1+i}{2})^n$.

Can anyone give me a hint to solve the problem?

Comment: Hint: look at the absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

One may use the fact that, for any $|q|<1$, we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}n|q|^n=0.
$$ Apply it here, observing that
$$
\left|n\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^n\right|\leq n\left|\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right|^n.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$\frac{(n+1)\left|\frac{1+i}{2}\right|^{n+1}}{n\left|\frac{1+i}{2}\right|^n}\underset{n\to\infty }{\longrightarrow} \left|\frac{1+i}{2}\right|<1$$

Comment: This is the ratio test which garantees the convergence, but that doesn't give me the limit of $n(\frac{1+i}{2})^n$.

Comment: Of course it does ! If $\sum_{n}x_n$ converge, what is $\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n$ ?

Comment: Are you referring to generating functions?

Comment: No. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Answer (score -1):

Consider that :

$$(1+i)^4 = ((1+i)^2)^2=(1+2i-1)^2=4i^2=-4$$

So for any $n=4(n\,div\,4)+(n\,mod\,4)$ we have :

$$\left|n\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^n\right|=n2^{-n+2(n\,div\,4)+(n\,mod\,4)}|(1+i)^{n\,mod\,4}|$$

Now the magnitude of this cannot ever be $>1$ so this converges to zero ( converging along distinct sets of values, but converging all the same to zero ).